# Google java spreadsheet API, update cell using the cell url

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I hope I'm describing what I need correctly, and hopefully maybe someone could shed some light and this.

I'm looking for the ability to update specific cell content in a worksheet based on the cell unique address.

As we can get for each cell it's address in R1C1 notation, is it possible for me to extract that address, manipulate it for my needs, (e.g. getting cell of R1C1, change it to R1C2) and update the cell in the new address?

If some more information required, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!
Meny

Comment: Could you provide a bit more clarity here (perhaps graphically)? Sounds like you want to copy a cell's value to a new cell and change its value?? Also, what technology are you trying to use here? Apps Script w/in the Spreadsheet or something that runs externally elsewhere?

Comment: Hey Arun,  my situation is as this, I would like to grab the data from Cell B1 only if Cell A1 meets a specific term. and same for A2,B2 etc... I'm using the google spreadsheet api V3 for java web applications. for now what I'm doing is to grab the whole row using the ListEntryFeed, break the cells into some data container, and if the value of A1 meets the term, i'm taking the value of B2 from the data container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's a little late but I think this can help you:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

specifically the part that says: 'Changing contents of a cell'